# Netbeans: How to change error row highlighting color away from red

Tags: netbeans

I've dug through every damn color setting under Tools> Options.  Went through every Fonts & Color, Editor, PHP etc and I'll be damned if I can figure out how to change the background row highlighting for when you have an error.  I've been able to change ever other color to fit my personal preference cept this one.   Here's a screen shot of the problem:

[image]

I would like to change the background red to a dark red so the text is easier to ready.

Using Netbeans 7.4

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Edit:  Per Ben's point, here's the current options and the code behind the panel to show it's not working:

[image]

Final update, here's the end result which is close enough:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By looking at your screenshots (correct me if I am wrong) I can see that you have set your current row highlighting to red:

Tools-> Options-> Fonts&Colors-> Highlighting(Tab)-> Highlight Caret Row

[image: Screenshot 1]

As far as I know you can't set different background highlighting options for errors. So what you can do is set the formatting options for errors:

1. **Font:** No need to explain this.
2. **Foreground:** This is the text color if you change this it will disregard all other formatting options that you may have set, so lets leave it as is.
3. **Background:** This is what you want to change so that text don't get lost in the formatting. If you scroll to the bottom you can also set custom colors.
4. **Effects:** Irrelevant
5. **Effect Color:** Disabled if effects is None and only applies to the effect.

[image: Screenshot 2]

As you can see I set mine to yellow just as an example.

As you can see in this screen shot my background highlighting is light grey as well as my string formatting. So it is impossible to read, but by changing the error formatting this is the result:

[image]

Alternatively you can just select another background highlighting color that suits your formatting better.

Comment: Close Enough.  Few comments:  Your first assumption was incorrect, I do not have anything special set for the Highlight Caret Row.  Your second part mostly did the trick.  The part that kept hanging me up was that if you click apply after changing the colors, nothing happens.  Even after you click ok and go back to your editor it was still red.  After clicking on the error row, then clicking off of it it changed the color.  Apparently you must force the code editor to re-render.   And lastly, the dark red highlight still extenders after the text ends to the right. I updated the original post.

Comment: Glad I could help in some way :) Quick question does the red highlighting appear on every selected line or only on lines with errors?

Comment: Only on the line with the error.  I added a screen shot to the original post at the bottom showing it.

Answer (score 2):

Try Fonts&Colors->Syntax->Error
[image]

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and it doesnt work or that's not the correct one.  I added a new screen shot with those options changed above.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try setting the Annotations color for "Error", mine was set to a specific color (after importing a theme) instead of 'Inherited', making text unreadable in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

This was really annoying for me too and most answers didn't help. I think that I have figured it out.
In netbeans 12 you need to change two things.

Tools->Options->Fonts&Colors->Syntax->Java->Error->change background color. This will only change the background of the code in error and not the red background of the rest of the lines white space.
To fix the red on the whitespace.
Tools->Options->Fonts&Colors->Annotations->Error(the one with the exclamation point)->change background color

I selected inherited to have no whitespace highlighting.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tM0cN.png)